# Kernel development

Tags: c, kernel

I'm trying to learn more about kernels, so naturally I started to program one. I'm using tutorials from [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page). Right now I have modified the `printf()` that was supplied there. It used `goto` and I didn't like that.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code? It worked fine when I tested it.

```
printf("hello %c world %c",'x','y')

int printf(const char* restrict format, ...)
{
   va_list parameters;
   va_start(parameters, format);

   int written = 0;
   size_t amount;

   while(*format != '\0')
   {
      if (*format != '%')
      {
    amount = 1;
    while(format[amount] && format[amount] != '%') //print every character until, % is encountered.
       amount++;
    print(format, amount);
    format += amount;       
    written += amount;
    continue;
      }
      switch(*(++format)) //since format points now to %, move on step
      {
         case 'c':
            format++;   //prepare next char
        char c = (char)va_arg(parameters, int);
        print(&c, sizeof(c));
        written++;
         break;
      }
   }
    return written;
}
```

And `print()`, left completely unmodified:

```
static void print(const char* data, size_t data_length)
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < data_length; i++ )
        putchar((int) ((const unsigned char*) data)[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You may need to document that this currently only works for the `c` option.  Others may assume otherwise that this can support all or most of them.  Of course, you don't have to do that since this is merely a reinvention of the wheel.
- Make sure to keep your indentation consistent.  It seems you're mostly using four spaces for it, so it should be done everywhere.  You should *especially* fix it in the large `if` statement.
- This looks a little unusual:

  > ```
  > switch(*(++format))
  > ```

  I assume you're doing this to avoid duplication, but based on your current code, it looks like you can still put it in the `switch` body without repetition.  Not having the increment in the statement itself may help with readability, too.
- You never check for errors, which is what the standard function does.  If an error occurs, you should set the error indicator `ferror` and then return a negative value.

  Be sure you're reading the documentation on this function to help improve your own.